# Cassandra startup issue

Tags: cassandra, restart, hector

First, I read this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534713/cassandra-startup-problem-attempt-to-assign-id-to-existing-column-family).

I cannot get Cassandra up and running again.
I am using Hector as my client to connect to an instance of Cassandra 0.8.2 & load my schema. Through Hector, I am using 2 different classes to create 2 different column families - Articles & TagsArticlesCF.

Through the main class, I  create a column families named "Articles" and "TagsArticlesCF" like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("test cluster", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9160");
    newKeyspaceDef = HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition(keyspaceName);
    if( (cluster.describeKeyspace(keyspaceName)) == null){
        createSchema();
    }


    Keyspace ksp = HFactory.createKeyspace(keyspaceName, cluster);
    Articles art = new Articles(cluster, newKeyspaceDef,ksp);
TagsArticlesCF tags = new TagsArticlesCF(cluster,newKeyspaceDef,ksp);
```

Here is an example of what my column families look like/ how they are created:

```
public Articles(Cluster cluster, KeyspaceDefinition ksp, Keyspace ksp2)  {
BasicColumnFamilyDefinition bcfDef = new BasicColumnFamilyDefinition();
        bcfDef.setName("Articles");
        bcfDef.setKeyspaceName("test3");
        bcfDef.setDefaultValidationClass(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE.getClassName());
        bcfDef.setKeyValidationClass(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE.getClassName());
        bcfDef.setComparatorType(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE);

        ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = new ThriftCfDef(bcfDef);
        BasicColumnDefinition columnDefinition = new BasicColumnDefinition();
        columnDefinition.setName(StringSerializer.get().toByteBuffer("title"));
        columnDefinition.setIndexType(ColumnIndexType.KEYS);
        columnDefinition.setValidationClass(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE.getClassName());
        cfDef.addColumnDefinition(columnDefinition);
...
```

I am trying to add a full schema into Cassandra that will support queries that I plan to execute on the loaded data. I ran the main method a few times to load the new column families into the database. After running the main method several times and adjusting a few things (checking if the column family was already in the KeyspaceDefinition), the running instance of Cassandra went down.

I am curious about a few things using Hector/java:

1. I plan to have 10 or so column families with different columns (to support different queries). Is it best practice to organize my classes so that I have a class for each column family?
2. What exactly is the difference between a KeyspaceDefinition & a Keyspace? Why is the distinction made?

We tried to get a new instance of Cassandra & here is what we ran into. I am trying to better understand what's going on so, any comments and help to avoid these types of errors would be greatly appreciated:

```
[root@appscluster1 bin]# ./cassandra -p cassandra.pid
[root@appscluster1 bin]#  INFO 10:52:36,437 Logging initialized
 INFO 10:52:36,484 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.6.0_25
 INFO 10:52:36,485 Heap size: 1046937600/1046937600
 INFO 10:52:36,490 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO 10:52:36,526 Loading settings from file:/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-0.8.2/conf/cassandra.yaml

[root@appscluster1 bin]#  INFO 10:52:36,872 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 10:52:37,346 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 332MB
 INFO 10:52:37,348 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:37,497 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:37,617 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:37,984 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:38,252 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:38,259 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:38,545 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/IndexInfo-g-73
 INFO 10:52:38,661 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/Schema-g-169
 INFO 10:52:38,685 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/Schema-g-170
 INFO 10:52:38,730 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/Schema-g-171
 INFO 10:52:38,751 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/Migrations-g-171
 INFO 10:52:38,763 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/Migrations-g-170
 INFO 10:52:38,776 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/Migrations-g-169
 INFO 10:52:38,795 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/LocationInfo-g-2
 INFO 10:52:38,827 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/system/LocationInfo-g-1
 INFO 10:52:39,048 Loading schema version ec437ac0-d28a-11e0-0000-c4ffed3367ff
 INFO 10:52:39,645 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:39,663 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
```

... (more of same)...

```
 INFO 10:52:40,463 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:41,390 Opening /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/test3/Articles-g-367
ERROR 10:52:41,392 Missing sstable component in /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/test3/Articles-g-367=[Index.db, Data.db]; skipped because of /opt/cassandra/persist8/data/test3/Articles-g-367-Index.db (No such file or directory)
 INFO 10:52:41,863 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
 INFO 10:52:41,865 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
```

... (more of same) ...

```
 INFO 10:52:41,892 Removing compacted SSTable files (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable)
ERROR 10:52:41,898 Exception encountered during startup.
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=ColumnFamilies,keyspace=test3,columnfamily=TagsArticlesCF
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:315)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:466)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:436)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.initCf(Table.java:369)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.<init>(Table.java:306)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:111)
       at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.setup(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:187)
       at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.activate(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:341)
       at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:80)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=ColumnFamilies,keyspace=test3,columnfamily=TagsArticlesCF
       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:453)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1484)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:963)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:917)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:312)
       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:311)
       ... 8 more
Exception encountered during startup.
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=ColumnFamilies,keyspace=test3,columnfamily=TagsArticlesCF
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:315)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:466)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:436)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.initCf(Table.java:369)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.<init>(Table.java:306)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:111)
       at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.setup(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:187)
       at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.activate(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:341)
       at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:80)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=ColumnFamilies,keyspace=test3,columnfamily=TagsArticlesCF
       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:453)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1484)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:963)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:917)
       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:312)
       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)
       at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:311)
       ... 8 more

[root@appscluster1 bin]#
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I figured out the difference between a KeyspaceDefinition and Keyspace. From here (http://groups.google.com/group/hector-users/browse_thread/thread/405dbc1b03e97e05)

Comment: I got the instance back up, but I cannot figure out why I got this error in the first place. It seems like an unstable situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you sending the Keyspace definition to the cluster?

Take a look at the methods following test case:
https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/test/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/service/CassandraClusterTest.java#L115-189

If a keyspace and or column family already exist, you should be able to catch an IllegalArgumentException.